# No puedo hacer build a una imagen en docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

No puedo crear una imagen de docker en un proyecto de django con postgres, y cuando ejecuto docker compose me da un error en la descarga de paquetes dentro de la imagen.

Este es el output.

```
cride_local_flower  2/20] RUN apk update   && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev   && apk add postgresql-dev   && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev   && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi   && apk add gettext   && apk add postgresql-client:
#0 10.84 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#0 15.88 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main: temporary error (try again later)
#0 15.88 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main: No such file or directory
#0 15.88 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#0 20.89 2 errors; 34 distinct packages available
#0 20.89 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community: temporary error (try again later)
#0 20.89 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community: No such file or directory
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk update   && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev   && apk add postgresql-dev   && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev   && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi   && apk add gettext   && apk add postgresql-client]: exit code: 2
```

No se me ocurre ninguna solución y esto me evita continuar con el proyecto, ya cambie la dns de docker a las de google para intentar un cambio y no funciono.

Si alguién me puede ayudar.

Comment: Has probado con otra versión de Alpine, aunque sea inferior?

Comment: Lo intente, pero creo que es docker que no me permite ejecutar instalaciones dentro de las imagenes, intente lo mismo con nodejs y npm y no descargaba nada tampoco.